# CSS class not being styled when it is rendered after an <hr> tag

Tags: html, css

I have a page that is listing links to other websites. Each link is followed by a brief description of the site being linked to. I want the link text to be slightly larger than the description so I added a CSS class definition a.link, in which I define font-size as 16px. The complete list is inside a standard `<p>` tag and I have `<hr>` tags in between each list item. The problem is that only the first link in the list gets the new font-size. Each link after the first loses all styles defined not only in the link class definition, but in the `<p>` tag as well. If I remove the `<hr>` tags, every item in the list is correctly styled. If I wrap each link in the list inside a `<p>` tag, they also are styled correctly, but I'd rather not clutter up the list with extra tags if possible

Here is my stylesheet code:

```
#pane {
    float: right;
    width: 800px;
}

#pane p {
    margin-left: 15px;
    font-family: verdana;
    font-size: 12px;
}

#pane p a.link { font-size: 16px; }
```

Here is a sample of the HTML generated:

```
<div id="pane">
<p>
    <a href="http://www.google.com" class="link">Google</a> - For finding stuff
    <hr>
    <a href="http://www.newegg.com" class="link">Newegg</a> - For buying stuff
    <hr>
</p>
</div>
```

Has anyone else encountered this behavior and found a way to fix it with adding `<p>` tags everywhere?

Comment: http://www.webmasterworld.com/html/3560080.htm

Answer (score 2):

Is it necessary to wrap it as a paragraph?  If not then you can lose that tag and then it works without that clutter. http://jsfiddle.net/bqhC9/

```
<div id="pane">
    <p>
        <a href="http://www.google.com" class="link">Google</a> - For finding stuff
    </p>
        <hr>
    <p>    
        <a href="http://www.newegg.com" class="link">Newegg</a> - For buying stuff
    </p>    
        <hr>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't put an `<hr>` inside of a `<p>` tag. If you try to, the browser automatically corrects it by closing the `<p>` tag for you.  The second link is no longer within a `<p>` element and so your CSS rules no longer apply.

This is what the browser fixes your code to and why your CSS classes are no longer applied.

```
<div id="pane">
<p>
    <a href="http://www.google.com" class="link">Google</a> - For finding stuff
    </p><hr>
    <a href="http://www.newegg.com" class="link">Newegg</a> - For buying stuff

<p></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

A collection of links is probably more suited to an unordered list (`UL`) perhaps inside a `NAV`.

Your issue is caused because `HR` inside of `P` doesn't [validate](http://validator.w3.org/) (and for a good reason). To confirm, I used this sample:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="pane">
<p>
    <a href="http://www.google.com" class="link">Google</a> - For finding stuff
    <hr>
    <a href="http://www.newegg.com" class="link">Newegg</a> - For buying stuff
    <hr>
</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

> A p element’s end tag may be omitted if the p element is immediately
>   followed by an ...HR...

<sup>Source: http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/p.html#p</sup>

As @Bill pointed out, this leads to the parser closing the `P` when you don't expect it.

An `HR` [reprsents a thematic break](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/hr.html#hr), which is semantically invalid inside of a paragraph. Logically (at least in English) a paragraph is supposed to [contain a collection of related thoughts on a single theme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paragraph), so this makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

hr can't in p tag. you can change p tag to div

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#pane {
float: right;
width: 800px;
}

#pane div {
  margin-left: 15px;
  font-family: verdana;
  font-size: 12px;
}

#pane div a.large    { font-size: 26px; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="pane">
<div>
    <a href="http://www.google.com" class="large">Google</a> - For finding stuff
    <hr/>
    <a href="http://www.newegg.com" class="large">Newegg</a> - For buying stuff
    <hr/>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Good answer on the `<p>, <hr>`
You'd be better off not using the `<p>`.

Style the `a.link` into `display:block` which will display the a tag just like the enclosing `<p>` tag.

Also auto-close your `<hr/>`

Then correct your css selector: `#pane > a.link` if you need to actually be that selective.  Probably better to just style `a.link` by itself, so that you can overwrite it with another selector later if required and not have issues with [specificity](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/).

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have problem with your HR tag, 
in XHTML you have to close your tag.
So your HR should look like `<hr/>`

```
    <div id="pane">
<p>
    <a href="http://www.google.com" class="link">Google</a> - For finding stuff
    <hr/>
    <a href="http://www.newegg.com" class="link">Newegg</a> - For buying stuff
    <hr/>
</p>
</div>
```

Than it should work, no reason not to.